"Muting" a chat doesn't work
I would like to "mute" a chat so that I do not continue to receive messages from that chat.
I have selected to Mute and the mute icon is showing next to the chat title but messages posted to the chat still come through. Essentially, I want to leave the chat.
Am I not understanding the Mute command on the chat correctly?

Is this enterprise Teams, or a personal account?

It is Enterprise

You will need to work with your designated IT staff then. If they're unable to resolve this, they'll be able to use their enterprise licenses with Microsoft to get support regarding this issue.
